# AutoMapper: One-to-many -> Many-to-many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper, entity-framework-core

I'm fairly new to AutoMapper. I have a hard time configuring AutoMapper to being able to map `UserViewModel` with multiple `TagViewModel` into a many-to-many relationship (`RecipeEntity <-> TagEntity`) which is needed for Entity Framework Core where `UserAndTagEntity` is the joining table.

Data Objects:

```
public class TagEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserAndTagEntity> UserAndTags { get; set; } = new List<UserAndTagEntity>();
}

public class UserEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserAndTagEntity> UserAndTags { get; set; } = new List<UserAndTagEntity>();
}

public class UserAndTagEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual UserEntity User { get; set; }
    public virtual TagEntity Tag { get; set; }
}

public class UserViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<TagViewModel> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class TagViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Test Example:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<UserEntity, UserViewModel>()
        .ForMember(
            dto => dto.Tags,
            opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.UserAndTags.Select(y => y.Tag)));

    cfg.CreateMap<UserViewModel, UserEntity>()
        .ForMember(
            dto => dto.UserAndTags,
            opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Tags))
        .AfterMap((model, entity) =>
        {
            foreach (var entityUserAndTag in entity.UserAndTags)
            {
                entityUserAndTag.User = entity;
            }
        });

    cfg.CreateMap<TagViewModel, UserAndTagEntity>();
});

var user = new UserViewModel()
{
    Name = "User",
    Tags = new List<TagViewModel>
    {
        new TagViewModel {Name = "Tag 1"},
        new TagViewModel {Name = "Tag 2"},
        new TagViewModel {Name = "Tag 3"},
        new TagViewModel {Name = "Tag 4"},
    }
};

IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var map = mapper.Map<UserViewModel, UserEntity>(user);
```

This works partly - The issue I've is that `Tag` on `UserAndTagEntity` is null.

Comment: What exact mapping operation is causing you troubles? Can you show the usage case.

Comment: Ivan: I've added an example to my question. But overall I'm unsure how to add the `Tag` reference to `UserAndTagEntity`.

Comment: What is `_mapper`? I've tried `var _mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<TestMapper>()).CreateMapper();` but then the sample code is throwing exception (due to the usage of the global `Mapper.Map` inside the mapping profile).

Comment: Ivan: I have simplified the test example so you can copy-paste it into a console application.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The mapping from `UserViewModel` to `UserEntity` can be achieved with the following configuration:

```
CreateMap<UserViewModel, UserEntity>()
    // (1)
    .ForMember(entity => entity.UserAndTags, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model.Tags))
    // (5)
    .AfterMap((model, entity) =>
    {
        foreach (var entityUserAndTag in entity.UserAndTags)
        {
            entityUserAndTag.User = entity;
        }
    });

// (2)
CreateMap<TagViewModel, UserAndTagEntity>()
    // (3)
    .ForMember(entity => entity.Tag, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model));

// (4)
CreateMap<TagViewModel, TagEntity>();
```

**Explanation:**

The line (1) is needed because the target and source property *names* do not match, so we just tell AutoMapper to map `Tags` property of the `UserViewModel` to `UserAndTags` property of the `UserEntity`.

Note that the mapping does not require that the source and target property *types* match. If they don't (as in this case), AutoMapper will map them using a separate configuration.

In our case, the source property type is `IList<TagViewModel>` and target property type is `ICollection<UserAndTagEntity>`. Ignore the collection types - AutoMapper knows how to convert them. What it doesn't know and needs to be specified is the mapping between the *element types*. In our case, from `TagViewModel` to `UserAndTagEntity`. Hence the need of mapping (2).

Inside the mapping (2), we have only one of the parts, so we use (3) to specify that - i.e. we map `TagViewModel` to `Tag` property of the `UserAndTagEntity`. Again the types do not match, so we need the mapping (4) from `TagViewModel` to `TagEntity`.

With all that the final result will be `UserEntity` instance with `UserAndTags` collection populated with `UserAndTagEntity` instances having correct `Tag` property. Then the step (5) is used to populate the `User` property of these instances.

Comment: Hi Ivan, thank you so much for your time and great explanation! I'm sending some good karma your way